# How to compute the standard deviation of a free fermionic random correlation matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, probability

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05339) on free random fermions. That is, fermions governed by
$$
H = \sum_{ij} t_{ij}c^{\dagger}_ic_j\quad \longrightarrow \quad H = \sum_k E_k d^{\dagger}_kd_k, 
$$
with $t_{ij}$ taken from the GOE ensemble. Given the eigenvectors of $t_{ij}$, $\{\psi^a\}$, the author claims that

> In relation to the eigenvectors, the main assertion is that the orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors $(\psi_1, · · · , \psi_N)$ is distributed according to the Haar measure on the orthogonal group $O(N)$.

which he then clarifies a bit by saying

> For our purposes, this means that the eigenvectors have independent and random gaussian entries, up to normalization. Mathemathically:
> $$[\psi_i^a]=0 \quad[\psi^a_i\psi^b_j]= \frac{1}{N}\delta_{ij}\delta^{ab},$$ where $[p]$ denotes the average of the random variable $p$ over the matrix ensemble.

where $\psi^a_i$ is the $i$-th entry of eigenvector $\psi^a$.

They proceed to calculate $[C_{ij}^{\Psi}]=[\langle c^\dagger_i c_j \rangle_\Psi] = \sum_{a\in \Psi}[\psi^a_i\psi^a_j]=N_p \delta _{ij}/N$, which I understand. But

**How does the author obtain**
$$
[C_{ij}^\Psi C_{kl}^\Psi] - [C_{ij}^\Psi][C_{kl}^\Psi] = \frac{N_p}{N^2} \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} \quad ?
$$
The last two terms are $\frac{N_p^2}{N^2}\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}$ which imply that the first term is $\frac{N_p}{N^2} \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\frac{N_p^2}{N^2}\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}$, why is this so?

**Furthermore, in general, what is $[\psi^a_i \psi^b_j \psi^c_k \psi^d_l]$?**

---

I get that $[\psi^a_i\psi^b_j] \propto \delta_{ij}\delta^{ab}$, if they say $\psi^a_i$ is an independent gaussian random variable then unless $\psi_i^a=\psi_j^a$ the expectation is $0$ as the gaussian integral is odd (i.e. $[x]=0, [x^2]=1$). (I don’t see where the factor of $1/N$ comes from though.) I would expect $[\psi^a_i \psi^b_j \psi^c_k \psi^d_l]$ to be proportional to $3 \delta_{ijkl}^{abcd}$, for the case $[x^4]=3$, and $\delta_{ij}^{ab}\delta_{kl}^{cd}+\delta_{ik}^{ac}\delta_{jl}^{bd}+\delta_{il}^{ad}\delta_{jk}^{bc}$ no?

---

Edit: This is a wild guess but if Wick’s theorem applies, one yields
$$
[C^\Psi_{ij} C^\Psi_{kl}]\equiv \sum_{a\in N_p} \sum_{b\in N_p}[\psi_i^a\psi^a_j\psi_k^b\psi^b_l]= \sum_{\cdots} ([\psi^a_i \psi^a_j][\psi^b_k\psi^b_l]+[\psi_i^a\psi^b_k][\psi^a_j\psi^b_l]+[\psi^a_i\psi^b_l][\psi^a_j\psi^b_k])=\sum_{a,b\in N_p}\frac{1}{N^2}(\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}+\delta^{ab}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta^{ab}\delta_{il}\delta_{jk})=\frac{N_p^2}{N^2} \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}+\frac{N_p}{N^2}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\frac{N_p}{N^2}\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}
$$
which is almost what the paper has, except for the extra term:
$$
[C_{ij}^\Psi C_{kl}^\Psi] - [C_{ij}^\Psi][C_{kl}^\Psi] = \frac{N_p}{N^2} (\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk})
$$

Comment: The formula in question looks strange. Expression $C^\Psi_{ij} = \sum_a \psi^a_i\psi^a_j$ is symmetric with respect to $i$ and $j$. This symmetry cannot disappear when averaging any combinations of  $C^\Psi_{ij}$. Is it possible that the formula in the article is wrong?

Comment: @Gec I believe they claim in the article that the eigenvectors are (or can be chosen to be) real, i.e. $\overline{\psi^a_i}=\psi^a_i$. Thus expressions like $C_{ij}^\Psi =\sum_a \overline{\psi^a_i}\psi^a_j$ become symmetrical. Maybe the reality claim is wrong?

Comment: The eigenvectors of any real symmetric matrix can be chosen to be real.

Comment: @Gec that’s true, they say $V$ is real symmetrical.

Comment: @Gec please see my edit and tell me what you think, it my solve the symmetry question.

Comment: I think, your final expression is correct.

Comment: Can you choose a more descriptive title?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch sure, let me know what you think of the new one :)

Comment: Perfect! :) ____

Comment: Why would this be Wick's theorem what you suggest? [*] is the average over the random ensemble, not an expectation value. To me this looks like one of those theorems on the average/integration of tensor products of random matrices.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch So the equations in my edit are wrong? I called it a Wick’s theorem for the lack of a better name... it’s just a guess, I don't even know if it is true, I know that it holds for gaussian integrals and this looks very very similar.

Comment: Well, it's on you to prove that it is correct.